# Добавление пункта меню в существующее меню, по нажатии на кнопку

Tags: java, android

Есть существующее меню, по нажатии на три точки появляется три действующих пункта.
На экране есть кнопка, по первому нажатии на которую, необходимо добавить четвертый пункт меню. Еще одно нажатие - пятый пункт меню, еще одно нажатие - шестой пункт меню.

Как я думал сделать:
Я изначально создал 6 пунктов меню в menu_main.xml, три из которых задал свойство visible:false.
Существует обработчик команд первых трех пунктов меню (toast-сообщение, вывод информации в log и отображение диалогового сообщения). 4-6 пункты могут просто отображать toast's.

Далее через onClick пытался изменить свойство visible на true, но что то делаю не так и появляется ошибка Cannot resolve method 'setVisibility(int)'. Как мне подключится к редактированию этого свойства в пункте меню?

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnClickListener {

    private static final String TAG = "myLogs";
    Button button;
    TextView textView4;
    EditText editText;
    private Object Menu;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        textView4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        final Menu action_item4 = (Menu) findViewById(R.id.action_item4);


        button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Menu action_item4 = (Menu) findViewById(R.id.action_item4);
                 action_item4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                          }
        });
    }
```

}
}

Answer (score 0):

Перегрузите данный метод активности

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu( Menu menu ){
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu( menu );
}
```

В нем есть параметр Menu, вот через него и управляйте видимостью, но учтите что изначальное состояние всегда будет то, которое вы создали в методе onCreateOptionsMenu.

Comment: Наверное что то не понимаю. Эта часть кода не работает.

Comment: @test_pilot вы меню создаете в onCreateOptionsMenu ?

Comment: да, в onCreateOptionsMenu